# Split columns into three+ divs?

Tags: columns

I got this code *([source](http://www.sitepoint.com/split-wordpress-content-into-multiple-sections/))*

```
// split content at the more tag and return an array
function split_content() {
    global $more;
    $more = true;
    $content = preg_split('/<span id="more-\d+"><\/span>/i', get_the_content('more'));
    for($c = 0, $csize = count($content); $c < $csize; $c++) {
        $content[$c] = apply_filters('the_content', $content[$c]);
    }
    return $content;
}

// original content display
// the_content('<p>Read the rest of this page &raquo;</p>');
// split content into array
$content = split_content();
// output first content section in column1
echo '<div id="column1">', array_shift($content), '</div>';
// output remaining content sections in column2
echo '<div id="column2">', implode($content), '</div>';
```

This only gets two columns - how can I get a third div column?

Cheers!

Comment: Please always provide _full_ code. There's no guarantee that the source will live forever.

Comment: Close-voted as **off-topic**. This is an **HTML/PHP** question, *not* a **WordPress** question. (Note: while asked in the *context* of WordPress, this question boils down to "*how do I take this blob of content and break it into columns?*". Since you already know how to retrieve/filter `the_content` in WordPress, you've eliminated anything *WordPress* specific in the question. **Suggestion**: if the content in question uses the `<!--nextpage-->` tag to split columns, then this question **can** be made WordPress-specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right found a great solution from: http://digwp.com/2010/03/wordpress-post-content-multiple-columns/

functions.php:

```
function my_multi_col_v2($content){
// run through a couple of essential tasks to prepare the content
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);

// the first "more" is converted to a span with ID
$columns = preg_split('/(<span id="more-\d+"><\/span>)|(<!--more-->)<\/p>/', $content);
$col_count = count($columns);

if($col_count > 1) {
    for($i=0; $i<$col_count; $i++) {
        // check to see if there is a final </p>, if not add it
        if(!preg_match('/<\/p>\s?$/', $columns[$i]) )  {
            $columns[$i] .= '</p>';
        }
        // check to see if there is an appending </p>, if there is, remove
        $columns[$i] = preg_replace('/^\s?<\/p>/', '', $columns[$i]);
        // now add the div wrapper
        $columns[$i] = '<div class="dynamic-col-'.($i+1).'">'.$columns[$i].'</div>';
    }
    $content = join($columns, "\n").'<div class="clear"></div>';
}
else {
    // this page does not have dynamic columns
    $content = wpautop($content);
}
// remove any left over empty <p> tags
$content = str_replace('<p></p>', '', $content);
return $content;
```

}

replace your the_content() tag with the following code:

```
$content = get_the_content('',FALSE,''); // arguments remove 'more' text
```

echo my_multi_col_v2($content);

Add CSS:

```
div.dynamic-col-1 { float: left; width: 38%; padding-right: 2%;}
div.dynamic-col-2 { float: left; width: 38%;padding-right: 2%;}
div.dynamic-col-3 { float: left; width: 20%;}
div.clear { clear: both; }
```

add the two `<!--more-->` tags in your post/page content to create the three columns.

Answer (score 0):

With the above shown function `split_content()` it's not possible to build a three column layout. It basically splits the content with the `<!-- more -->`-Tag into half and then builds two columns (in a pretty complicated way).

Maybe it works with adding multiple `<!--more-->`-Tags to your post content in the HTML-Editor.